# converting Text on bitmap to a string android

Tags: android, encoding, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am trying to set up OCR functionality by converting a bitmap into byte array and then a byte array to  String ..     This is what I have tried

```
{
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            img.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, boas);
            byte[] b = boas.toByteArray();
            String str3=b.toString();
            Log.i("string ", "***** "+str3);
            String str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            txt.setText("STR  "+str);
            Log.i("string ", "****str***** "+str);
            String str2 = new String(b,"UTF-8");
            Log.i("string ", "****str***** "+str2);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);

        }
```

But result I am getting is Quite out of relevance

Comment: Do you want to extract text from image (OCR) or convert raw image bytes to Base64?

Comment: yes exactly I want to extract text from image . Do we have any api's or other work around for this.

Comment: No, there's no default OCR library in java/android. Use third-party ones.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [ABBY CLOUD OCR SDK](http://ocrsdk.com/). They have free trial so you can check it.